# Load more image from instagram API giving me same images

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, instagram

I'm using Instagram PHP API with Ajax to get user media stream, it gave me same images per each request.

Here is the page code :

```
/**
   * Instagram PHP API
   *
   * @link https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API
   * @author Christian Metz
   * @since 20.06.2012
   */

  require_once 'api/instagram.class.php';

  // Initialize class for public requests
  $instagram = new Instagram('CLIENT_ID');


  // Get recently tagged media
  $media = $instagram->getUserMedia(USER_ID, LIMIT_NUMBER);

  // Display first results in a <ul>
  echo "<ul id=\"photos\">";
  foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$data->images->standard_resolution->url}\"><li><img src=\"{$data->images->low_resolution->url}\"></li></a>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";

  // Show 'load more' button
  echo "<br><div id='content'><div id='spinner'><img src='/wp-content/themes/tmg/ui/img/spinner.png' id=\"more\" data-maxid=\"{$media->pagination->next_max_id}\"></div></div>";
```

And it is AJAX.PHP

```
  /**
   * Instagram PHP API
   *
   * @link https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API
   * @author Christian Metz
   * @since 20.06.2012
   */

  require_once 'api/instagram.class.php';

  // Initialize class for public requests
  $instagram = new Instagram('CLIENT_ID');

  // Receive AJAX request and create call object
  $tag = $_GET['tag'];
  $maxID = $_GET['max_id'];
  $clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();

  $call = new stdClass;
  $call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
  $call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4563432423/media/recent?max_id=436456456456456456&client_id=9089798ayut675675757a";

  // Receive new data
$media = $instagram->getUserMedia('76766456534', 32); 

  // Collect everything for json output
  $images = array();
  foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    $images[] = $data->images->low_resolution->url;
  }

  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
    'images'  => $images
  ));
```

AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#more').click(function() {
    var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
        maxid = $(this).data('maxid');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/ajax.php',
      data: {
        tag: tag,
        max_id: maxid
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // Output data
        $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
          $('ul#photos').append('<li><img src="' + src + '"></li>');
        });
    });
  });
});
```

My API request is successful, so what is obvious something in the code is wrong, i'm not very PHP knowledgeable, Anyone has done it before so can help me out with?

Comment: Can you also post your JS for ajax requests?

Comment: @eithedog just added to the post

Comment: Are you actually using `$call` anywhere aside from setting some class properties?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are hard-coding the next page when you suppose to get it from the first ajax response (`data.pagination.next_url`) ... then pass that to the next ajax request

Answer (score 0):

When the PHP page is initial rendered to HTML

```
data-maxid=\"{$media->pagination->next_max_id}
```

will cause **data-maxid** to always be the same number (I'm assuming, since this is an ajax request the page doesn't get reloaded).

One solutions would be to have your ajax request's "on complete" callback update the data-maxid attribute.

It look's as though you are passing back the next Id already (`'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id`), you just need to have the js update the data attribute.

Might look something like this if you are using jQuery:

```
//ajax onComplete callback
function(result){
   $('#more').data('maxid', result.next_id);
}
```

**Update**

I'm not 100% sure but this change may work:

```
  //this probably shouldn't be static...
  $call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4563432423/media/recent?max_id=" . $maxId . "&client_id=9089798ayut675675757a";
  // Receive new data
  $media = $instagram->pagination($call);
```

Looking at the [PHP library doc](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API), it appears that to page you just pass the original object back into the "pagination" function.

What your doing with `$call` might contain the necessary fields to complete the request, otherwise it will likely throw an error.

Comment: Actually i used this code to get the specific hashtag and it was working and MAX_ID was working fine.

Comment: I just posted my AJAX request into original post. Could you please take a look and correct it when you have a chance?

Comment: @Amir look at the update to my answer.  Basically you need to recreate the original media object you received (hopefully excluding the actual images) and pass that into the pagination method.

Comment: looks like you were hardcoding the nexturl.  I updated it one more time.  If this doesn't work, then can you please post the object returned by this call: "$media = $instagram->getUserMedia(USER_ID, LIMIT_NUMBER);"